# Jquery and CSS contact form. how to add email submit?

Tags: jquery, forms, contact-form

Im having trouble understanding how to add my submit button to my email, I tried to add mailto: in the action but that didn't work. It works along side Jquery.

What is wrong? I'm not so good with php and thought this css/jquery contact form would be better for me. But where to put my email to the client can fill the form and click submit?

Thanks.

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
   
  file_style();
  
  $('form').bind("submit", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
  });
  
  $(".contact input").keyup(function() {
   var value =$(this).val();
      var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
      
       if($(this).parent().hasClass("email")){
         if(!reg.test($(this).val())){
           validate_animation($(this), "error");
      error_message($(this), "error");
         }
         else{
           validate_animation($(this), "success");
      error_message($(this), "success");
         }
         exit;
        }
    if(value.length > 0){
     validate_animation($(this), "success");
     error_message($(this), "success");
    }
        else if(value.length == 0){
     validate_animation($(this), "blank");
     error_message($(this), "blank");
     }
    else
    {
     validate_animation($(this), "error");
     error_message($(this), "error");
    }
  });
  
  $(".contact input").blur(function(){
   error_message($(this), "blank");
  });

}); 

function validate_animation(elem, is_valid){

 if(is_valid != "blank"){
  var elem_class = elem.attr("class").split("-");
  elem.attr("class",elem_class[0] + "-to-" + is_valid);
 }
 else{
  elem.attr("class", "default");
 }
 
}

function error_message(elem, is_valid){
 if(is_valid == "error"){
  var msg = elem.attr("msg"); 
  elem.next().text(msg).show();
 }
 else{
  elem.next().hide();
 }
}

function file_style(){

 var wrapper = $('<div/>').css({height:0,width:0,'overflow':'hidden'});
 var fileInput = $(':file').wrap(wrapper);

 fileInput.change(function(){
  $this = $(this);
 })

 $('#file').click(function(){
  fileInput.click();
 }).show();
}


(function () {
 var input = document.getElementById("images"), 
     form = document.getElementById("image-form"),
     dropbox = document.getElementById("file"),
  formdata = false;

 function showUploadedItem (source) {
    $("#image-list").html("<li><img src='"+source+"' />");
 }   
 
 function dragEnter(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   evt.preventDefault();
 }

 function dragOver(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   evt.preventDefault();
    $('#file').css("background-position" , "center -140px");
   $('#file p').text("Release to add image").css("cursor" , "alias");
 }
 
 function dragExit(evt) {
   evt.stopPropagation();
   evt.preventDefault();
   $('#file').css("background-position" , "center 35px");
   $('#file p').text("Click or Drag in an image to upload").css("cursor" , "pointer");
 }
 
 function handleFiles(files) {
  var file = files[0]; 
  if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
   if ( window.FileReader ) {
      reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
       showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
     }
   }
 }
 
 function drop(evt){
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
   
  var files = evt.dataTransfer.files;
  var count = files.length; 
  // Only call the handler if 1 or more files was dropped.
  if (count > 0){
   handleFiles(files);
  }
 }
 
 if (window.FormData) {
    formdata = new FormData();
 }
 
 // init event handlers
 dropbox.addEventListener("dragenter", dragEnter, false);
 dropbox.addEventListener("dragexit", dragExit, false);
 dropbox.addEventListener("dragover", dragOver, false);
 dropbox.addEventListener("drop", drop, false);
 
 
  input.addEventListener("change", function (evt) {
   //document.getElementById("response").innerHTML = "Uploading . . ."
   var i = 0, len = this.files.length, img, reader, file;
 
  for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
   file = this.files[i];
 
   if (!!file.type.match(/image.*/)) {
    if ( window.FileReader ) {
     reader = new FileReader();
     reader.onloadend = function (e) { 
      showUploadedItem(e.target.result, file.fileName);
     };
     reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
    if (formdata) {
     formdata.append("images[]", file);
    }
   } 
  }
 }, false);
   
}());

    
    
    </script>
```

```css
 *{

  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: 'caviar_dreamsregular';
  font-weight:700;
  font-size:12px;
  color:#333;
  padding:0px;
  margin:0px;
  border:0;
  
 }
 
  ::selection
 {
  color:inherit;
 }
 ::-moz-selection
 {
  color:inherit;
 } 
 
  
  
 
.contact{
 position:relative;
 width:60%;
 max-width:700px;
 margin:0 auto 0%;
 padding:10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -o-border-radius: 5px;
 -ms-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px; 
 background:rgba(0,0,0,0.05);
    
}

.three_col , .one_col{
 float:left;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
    
}
 
.three_col input, .one_col input, .three_col select, .one_col textarea, .one_col  #file {
 position:relative;
 padding:5px 5px;
 margin:1% 2%;
 float:left;
 z-index:10;
 border:1px solid #ccc; background:url(http://www.olliehusbanddesign.co.uk/form/images/tick.jpg) 120% 0 no-repeat #fff;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box;
}

.three_col span.error, .one_col span.error{
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    display: block;
    font-size: 10px;
    height: 35px;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -33px;
 left:25%;
    width: auto;
 z-index:999999999;
 display:none;
}

.three_col span.error:nth-child(5){
 left:65%;
}

.three_col span.error:after, .one_col span.error:after{
 background: url("http://www.olliehusbanddesign.co.uk/form/images/popup_arrow.png") repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    bottom: -7px;
    content: "";
    height: 7px;
    left: 47%;
    position: absolute;
    width: 17px;
} 
.three_col select{
 width:16%;
 background:#fff;
 padding:4px;
}
.three_col input{
 width:36%;
} 

.one_col input, .one_col textarea, .one_col  #file {
 width:96%;
}

.one_col  #file {
  background: url("http://www.olliehusbanddesign.co.uk/form/images/Camera_icon.png") no-repeat scroll center 35px transparent;
    border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    width: 96%; 
}

.one_col  #file p{
padding: 95px 0 0;
line-height: 40px;
}

.one_col #image-list li{
 list-style:none; 
 border:1px solid #ccc; 
 margin: 2%;
 background:#fff;
}

.one_col #image-list li img{
 width:98%;
 height:98%;
 margin: 1% !important;
}

.one_col #submit{
 
   background: #4d4d4d;
   color: #d6d6d6;
   cursor:pointer;
}

.one_col #submit:hover{
 background: #333;
   color: #d6d6d6;
} 

.clear{
 clear:both;
 content:"";
 line-height:0px;
 display: block;
}

/* old browser fixed */

.no-rgba .contact,  .no-rgba .three_col span.error,  .no-rgba .one_col span.error{
 background:url(http://www.olliehusbanddesign.co.uk/form/images/norgba_bg.png) !important;
}

.no-canvas .one_col, .no-canvas .three_col, .no-canvas .one_col input, .no-canvas .three_col input{
 float:right !important; 
 margin-right:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
}

.no-canvas .three_col input{
 width:34% !important;
 margin-right:0;
 margin-bottom:0;
 float:right;
}


.no-canvas .file-upload  div{
 display:block !important;
 height:auto !important;
 width: 45% !important;
 float:right;
}

.no-canvas .one_col  #file{
 display:none !important;
}

/* animations */


@-moz-keyframes default-to-error {
 0%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    }
 50%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes default-to-success {
   0%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    }
 50%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes error-to-success {
    0%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    } 
 50%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    } 
 60%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    }
 100%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes success-to-error {
    0%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    } 
 50%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    } 
 60%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    }
 100%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes default-to-error {
 0%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    }
 50%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes default-to-success {
   0%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    }
 50%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes error-to-success {
    0%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    } 
 50%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    } 
 60%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    }
 100%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    }
}

@-webkit-keyframes success-to-error {
    0%{
        background-position:right 0px;
    } 
 50%{
        background-position:120% 0px;
    } 
 60%{
        background-position:120% -28px;
    }
 100%{
        background-position:right -28px;
    }
}


input.default-to-error{
 -webkit-animation: default-to-error 0.5s;
 -moz-animation: default-to-error 0.5s;
 -animation: default-to-error 0.5s;
   background-position:right -28px;   
   -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(243,38,36, 0.6); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(243,38,36, 0.6); 
 box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(243,38,36, 0.6); 
}

input.default-to-success{
 -webkit-animation: default-to-success 0.5s;
 -moz-animation: default-to-success 0.5s;
 -animation: default-to-success 0.5s;
   background-position:right 0px;    
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(161,199,54, 0.6); 
 -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(161,199,54, 0.6); 
 box-shadow:0 0 7px rgba(161,199,54, 0.6); 
}


@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
 
 .contact{
  width:90%;
 }
 
 .one_col  #file{
  width:96%;
 }
 
 .three_col input, .one_col input, .three_col select, .one_col textarea{
  width:96%;
  margin:2% 2%;
 }
 
 .three_col input, .one_col input{
  padding-right: 21px;
 } 
 
 .three_col span.error, .one_col span.error{
  display:none !Important;
 }
}
```

```html
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="#" id="image-form">
  <div class="three_col">
   <select>
     <option value="title">Title</option>
     <option value="mr">MR</option>
     <option value="mrs">MRS</option>
     <option value="ms">MS</option>
     <option value="dr">DR</option>
   </select>
   <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" class="default" msg="Error for First name">
   <span class="error"></span>
   <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" class="default" msg="Error for Last name">
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col email">
   <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" class="default" msg="Please enter a valid email">
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
   <input type="text" name="Budget" placeholder="Your Budget" class="default" msg="Error for budget">
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
   <textarea rows="4" cols="20" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col file-upload">
   <div id="file"><ul id="image-list"><p>Click or Drag in an image to upload</p></ul></div>
   <input type="file" class="file" name="images" id="images"/>
   <span class="error"></span>
  </div>
  <div class="one_col">
   <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
  <span class="clear"></span>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your submit is handled here:

```
$('form').bind("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

So the form is not submitted at all, if you want to get an email with the form data you need to send the form first to a server-side script like `PHP`.

You can see here a nice tutorial with also attached the PHP scripts:
http://trevordavis.net/blog/ajax-forms-with-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

You will need something server side to send your Email. Checkout this example: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/sending-email-from-site/using-the-php-mail-function-to-send-emails

Otherwise you can use mailto

But it won't send a mail, just open the default mail client of the user.

Even using your current form you will need to call a server-side file to actually send the mail.

Here is a full example you can copy and change: 
https://gist.github.com/ajtroxell/6731408